# Regex/other method to read user email address on input and hide/show a div respectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I am trying to read the user email address on input and if it is hotmail.com or yahoo.com then then I will hide the div element. However I am still struggling to get the hotmail.com string to be found and matched.

Here is my code below..

javascript:

```
$().ready(function () {
           var userEmail = document.getElementById("Username");
           var paymentBox = document.getElementById("divPaymentMethod");
           $(userEmail).blur(function () {
               if ($(userEmail).val() != "") {
                   var Name = $(userEmail).val();
                   if (Name.indexOf("@hotmail.com") > -1) {
                       $(paymentBox).hide();
                   }
                   else {
                       $(paymentBox).show();
                   }
               }
           });
```

html:

Comment: Can you split the problem into two pieces? Check what value `Name` has (does it contain `"@hotmail.com"`? throw it to console or just use debugger) and then check for such a string if `.indexOf("@hotmail.com") > -1` is `true` for it (should be `true`).

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct as long as you are checking only "...@hotmail.com".

If you are using this .aspx page inside any master page then id of the username will be changed to like "ctl_something..Username".
And it is accessed by asp.net code through Username.ClientID.

So I think you are mistaking on that ID part.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is inside a master page. I've tried changing the UserName to UserName.ClientID but it still doesn't work...

Comment: If this javascript code is present where your textbox Username is available then change
var userEmail = document.getElementById("Username"); with 
var userEmail = ocument.getElementById('<%=UserName.ClientID%>');

Comment: I get an error saying that the UserName does not exist in the current context.. atlthough the javascript does appear on the same code page

Comment: My username textbox field is actually nested under

 <asp:CreateUserWizard  ID="CreateUserWizard2" >
<WizardSteps>
<asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep2" runat="server" >
<ContentTemplate>
<h5 class="text-center">Please complete the following fields to register for an account</h5>

Will this make a difference to the Id I am calling?

Comment: Can you please check if you can access that UserName.ClientID from code behind?

Comment: Yes, that's why it is giving you Username doesn't exists.
Try to see from code behind how you can access UserName text. You can try like CreateUserWizard2.UserName.ClientID and see if you can access that.

Comment: I can't access the ClientID still... although I can get to UserName via CreateUserWizard2.UserName

Comment: Is this UserName "CreateUserWizard2.UserName" which you are accessing here is a textBox or a string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102473/discussion-between-m-wilson-and-nitin-garg).

Answer (score 0):

this will help you to find out **@hotmail.com** and **@yahoo.com**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sub").click(function(){
              var v=$("#em").val();
             if(v.search("@hotmail.com")!=-1 || v.search("@yahoo.com")!=-1)
             {
                alert();
             }
            });
           });
   </script>
    <input type="text" id="em">
    <button id="sub">submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply although I am trying to read the user input in real time and not after them pressing a submit button.. any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

this provide you real-time checking

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#em").focusout(function(){
              var v=$("#em").val();
             if(v.search("@hotmail.com")!=-1 || v.search("@yahoo.com")!=-1)
             {
                alert();
             }
            });
           });
   </script>
    <input type="text" id="em">
```

Comment: i am not working with asp but i think jquery is common for asp or php